# keras is not working on docker container but not throwing errors though

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, keras

I'm working with Keras in a project, and Keras is somehow not working.

That's why I wanted to test it with an official project to see what happens. The code of the official project is [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keras-team/keras/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py)

I have a flask application for serving the project, since it is gonna be on a EC2 instance. The endpoint looks so:

```
@app.route('/ocr/test_keras', methods=['GET'])
def test_keras():
    Thread(target=continue_test_keras, args=()).start()
    return jsonify('Success')

def continue_test_keras():
    tk.run()
    print('tests done')
```

and `tk` looks so:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import tensorflow as tf


GRAPH = tf.get_default_graph()


def run():
    with GRAPH.as_default():
       ...
```

(I gotta use the graph, since I'm working with tensorflow and multi-threading, see [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2397))

Now the weird behavior. When it's inside the docker container the last thing that happens is this:

```
Total params: 669,706
Trainable params: 669,706
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
before compiling
after compiling
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/4
```

and the code is here:

```
    print('before compiling')

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=RMSprop(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    print('after compiling')

    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        verbose=1,
                        validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

    print('after training')
```

it means, it stocks somehow at `model.fit` as exactly as on my project, but it doesn't throw any error. And it never prints `after training`

However, if I try they same code outside the container, but with the same virtualenv and the same instance, it yields:

```
Total params: 669,706
Trainable params: 669,706
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
before compiling
after compiling
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/4
2018-02-27 10:21:46.917107: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
60000/60000 [==============================] - 11s 179us/step - loss: 0.2501 - acc: 0.9235 - val_loss: 0.1126 - val_acc: 0.9653
Epoch 2/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 11s 178us/step - loss: 0.1032 - acc: 0.9687 - val_loss: 0.1010 - val_acc: 0.9682
Epoch 3/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 11s 178us/step - loss: 0.0749 - acc: 0.9774 - val_loss: 0.0823 - val_acc: 0.9762
Epoch 4/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 11s 179us/step - loss: 0.0622 - acc: 0.9818 - val_loss: 0.0799 - val_acc: 0.9784
after training
```

And that's what should happen inside the container. (I reduce the epochs number to 4, just to know if it's processing the fit and not wait that long)

The same behavior occurs with `model.evaluate`. No errors, but it doesn't do anything else.

I don't have a clue what can be happening.

Comment: Simple: the docker container has very specific libraries and binaries that were compiled with very specific flags. Your host machine, even though it has the same python libraries, doesn't have the same underlining libraries/binaries with those same flags/dependencies -- i'm sure they're close, but close doesn't mean the same. Thus this error. You are the poster child that i will show off to my team for why NOT to use anything BUT docker. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this error, because I found out, that it doesn't have to do with the docker container. 
I entered to the docker container and executed there the code, and it worked.
So, I suppose it has to do with flask, uwsgi or supervisor.

I tried everything from here: [issue 2397](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2397) (`debug=False`, `graph as default with tensorflow as well as Keras Backend`, `daemon in thread to true`, etc...) and it still no working with tensorflow as backend. And the project is actually working with flask outside uswgi and supervisor.

**EDIT**

Well I'm gonna write the answer here, because it's easier.

The problem was with uwsgi. Somehow Keras didn't work there.

I just followed the instructions [of this github repo](https://github.com/jsmits/keras-inception-service) and now it's working.

Comment: I'm having the same issue (container stops at  epoch 1/1)  and I don't have any library named uwsgi. Could you please elaborate the solution?

Comment: Facing the same issue with LSTM model, after loading the model with `load_model`, not able to predict. It's just stuck over there. I'm having nginx and uwsgi.